# Extracting user added custom properties of SharePoint file through VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I connected the SharePoint to network drive.We have added few attributes like "status" and "Rejection reason" to SharePoint files. We want to extract those properties using VBA.

![Custom added [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99iwg.png)

We have tried accessing those properties using extended properties of document but it is not available there.

```
{

Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim oFSO, Oshell, ODir, wordapp, Doc As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
'Dim Doc As Document
Set Oshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("S:\Shared Documents\General\")
Set ODir = Oshell.Namespace("S:\Shared Documents\General\")

For Each oFile In ODir.Items
'MsgBox oFile.Status
'Workbook.Open file:=oFile
'Set Doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
'MsgBox Doc.BuiltinDocumentProperties("status")
For i = 0 To 1000


'MsgBox ODir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, 0).Value
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = ODir.GetDetailsOf(oFile, i)
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = ODir.GetDetailsOf(, i)


    Next

Next oFile

End Sub
}
```

Can you please help us in extracting those.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to use "CustomDocumentProperties" istead of "BuiltinDocumentProperties"

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is not available in CustomDocumentproperties too.